# Wordpress custom theme issue (It shows the same theme on admin)

Tags: wordpress, themes

i migrated from a standard website to a wordpress theme, but after a day, when i try to login on wp-admin, it shows the theme and a lot of errors like "headers already sent" on pluggable.php.

How can i do to show my custom template without the admin site changes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "headers already sent" warning indicates that the error display settings you have on the new server are stricter.

Because the errors are being showed the website cannot redirect you correctly.

Add the following to wp-config:

```
error_reporting(E_NONE);
ini_set('display_errors', FALSE);
```

This should help overcome that problem.

Also you should not be outputting anything in your `functions.php` file because the admin area includes it because you may want to make a complex theme that adds admin menu buttons for theme-configurations, kind-of like a plug-in

Comment: Greetings Mihai Stancu, i did what you told me but still the problem, have a look plz:
[link](http://i.imgur.com/820fh.png)

Comment: Do you have any code written by you in your `functions.php` file? If so is it just a function declaration or do you call functions from there too?

Comment: yes, i added the get_header();  get_sidebar(); & get_footer(); inside the functions, i removed and placed again on index now it works !

Comment: Well that was the problem, the functions file is included by the admin. That's because you may want to make a complex theme that adds admin menu buttons for theme-configurations. Kind-of like a plug-in.